# How to import a python package in pytest using relative import

Tags: python, pytest

```
my-proj
├── src
│   ├── main.py
└── test
│   ├── my_tests.py
```

I have the above directory structure for my python project. I have some unittests in the my_test.py and when I run them, I get the following error using following imports:

```
import os, sys
import json
from ..src import main
import unittest
```

running like this from my-proj/test/ directory: **python my_tests.py**

> from ..src import main
>
> ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package

Apologies if this was answered but i tried a few things, even included __ main __.py in both directories (src and test) but didn't work. Any idea how I can get this to work?
It is a FLASK application in python (main.py)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also write the following in `my_tests.py`

```
import sys
sys.path.append("../src/")
import main
```

Answer (score 0):

`__main__.py` has no effect on packages, only so you can run `python -m pkg`. You're probably thinking of `__init__.py`, which makes a directory a package.

In general, it'd be better to store tests in the directory structure alongside your source files, not in a separate structure. That way `pytest src/`, as discussed e.g. [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/pythonpath.html) will just work. (You may need to plant a `conftest.py` in `src/` to have Py.test recognize it as a source root and fix up things accordingly.)

Another way is to make your [package properly installable (`setup.py`, etc.)](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/), then install it in develop mode using `pip install -e .`.